# Problem displaying two graphs on a single chart using javascript and chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am currently having trouble displaying two charts simultaneously. The data

The code I have written ensures that the sensor data is sent over a websocket one at a time i.e. one sensor reading is sent over the websocket and then graphed, and then afterwards the other sensor reading is sent over the websocket and graphed. However my problem is that since they are sent one at a time, both readings are set to a single variable and then that single variable is graphed.

Since I am very new to javascript and using chart.js I have absolutely no idea how to fix this problem.

Essentially I want to sent two sensor values over a websocket, create a variable for each and then graph both values on a single chart.

So firstly the first snippet of code below ensures that the two sensor values are sent separately over the websocket:

```
void getData(){

  //Grabs data from sensor and formats it to json string
  String json;
  if(count%2==0)
  {
    Serial.println("Yes");
    json += "{\"value\":";
    json += Thermocouple->readCelsius();
    json += "}"; 
    count++;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("No");
    json += "{\"value\":";
    json += thermocouple.readCelsius();
    json += "}"; 
    count++;
  }
    webSocket.broadcastTXT(json.c_str(), json.length());
  }
```

after this the JSON string is parsed:

```
webSocket.onmessage = function(event)
{
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      var today = new Date();
      var t = today.getHours()+ ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + ...
      addData(t, data.value)
 }
```

addData function:

```
function addData(label, data)
 {
    dataPlot.data.labels.push(label);
    dataPlot.data.datasets[0].data.push(data);
    dataPlot.update();

  }
```

function for chart

```
function init(){
    webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':81/');
    dataPlot = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"),{
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [],
          label: "Thermocouple 1",
          borderColor: "#3e95cd",
          fill: true

          },
       {
          data: [],
          label: "Thermocouple 2",
          borderColor: "  #FF0000",
          fill: true

          }]
        }
      });
```

As I said I am very new to all of this so please have mercy :D

Essentially I want to sent two sensor values over a websocket, create a variable for each and then graph both values on a single chart.

At the moment the result of the code above is that both sensor values are plotted on a single line, alternating between the two sensor values.

Comment: did you write this code, or did someone give it to you to fix?

Comment: I wrote the code, but like I said I am very new to using javascript and chart.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the code working. Firstly sending the sensor values over the websocket:

```
 String json = "{\"value\":";
  json +=  Thermocouple->readCelsius();
  json += ",";
  json += "\"value2\":";
  json += double(thermocouple.readCelsius());
  json += "}"; 

  webSocket.broadcastTXT(json.c_str(), json.length());
```

Then parsing the json string and "extracting" the values:

```
webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log(data.value);
      console.log(data.value2);
      var today = new Date();
      var t = today.getHours()+ ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
      addData(t, data.value, data.value2)
    }
```

I logged the values to the console just to make sure that the values were parsed correctly. Finally adding the data to the graph:

```
function addData(label, data, data2){

    if(dataPlot.data.labels.length > maxDataPoints)removeData();
    dataPlot.data.labels.push(label);//x-values
    dataPlot.data.datasets[0].data.push(data);
    dataPlot.data.datasets[1].data.push(data2);

    dataPlot.update();

  }
```